# how to re-open Xcode debug log after device crashes, while debugging multiple devices

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I start each of three iPad's running my app in each one's own Xcode window, each showing the debug log (NSLog) output for each iPad.  So there are three windows showing three iPad's running my app.

When iPad #1 crashes, after a few minutes, my app view disappears and iPad home is shown.
But on Xcode, the window that was showing iPad #1 debug log switches to the debug log of one of the remaining iPad's that are still running.

How can I view the debug NSLog logs for iPad #1 again, so I can see what it was doing when it crashed?

Comment: Can you see it in the Log Navigator (CMD-7) by any chance?

Comment: Yes, that should be the solution. I've just done the same, can see historical debug logs. I believe the history gets deleted when you quit Xcode. Maybe there are temporary files stored on disk, rather than the log just being retained in memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that was it:
cmd-7
or
View menu > Navigators > Show Log Navigator

then find "Debug" row in the pane on the left, and DOUBLE-CLICK its little right-arrow icon on its left.

I was confused because I single-clicked and it updated the title of the tab of the window to the right but didn't update it.  Double-clicking opens a new window with the desired log.

Thanks!

Comment: Anyone know why the popup log window is double-lined?